# mySQL is not starting after installing WampServer 2

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

**The Problem:** I am trying to set a root password for mySQL after installing WampServer 2. Upon entering the default password which is *empty*, the console is freezing without any messages or errors.

I have attached below a picture of the problem:

[image]

In addition to that phpmyadmin is not loading.

**Notes:**

1. It's a fresh install of WampServer 2, i didn't change any settings or modified anything after installation.
2. localhost is working.

**My System Information:**

**Operating System:**       Windows 7 Home Premium (64Bit).
**WampServer Version:**     WampServer 2.2D (64bit).
**Apache:**                 2.2.21
**MySQL:**                  5.5.20
**PHP:**                    5.3.10
**PHPMyAdmin:**             3.4.10.1
**SQLBuddy:**               1.3.3
**XDebug:**                 2.1.2

Comment: Can you please read my possibly associated post here: http://superuser.com/questions/403920/command-prompt-hangs-freezes-crashes-sporadically and do a few tests to see if you get the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by two reasons.

1 .Your Window has some problem or may be affected by viruses.

2.The installer you are using is inappropriate.

Try changing the installer that will do